# I can't get my cookies to work for my website

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make cookies for a website that will save whether I'm in dark mode or not for each page. I keep getting the error in the console I quickly put in to make sure everything works when I activate the function in the dev console.

I've already tried tinkering around with the functions but nothing works. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I really have no experience.

```
const cookies = document.cookie;

function darkmodeCookieEdit () {
    if (cookies === "d = 0; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;") {
        //Edit Cookie
        document.cookie = "d =; path = /; expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
        document.cookie = "d = 1; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;";
        //Edit Page
        navbar.style.background = "#2b2b2b";
        navbar.style.color = "#ffffff";
        content.style.background = "#242323";
        content.style.color= "#ffffff"
        console.log(cookies);
    } else if (cookies === "d = 0; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;") {
        //Edit Cookie
        document.cookie = "d =; path = /; expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
        document.cookie = "d = 0; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;"
        console.log(cookies);
    } else {
        document.cookie = "d =; path = /; expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
        document.cookie = "d = 0; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;";
        console.error("Darkmode cookies broken.");
        console.log(cookies);
    }
}
```

It always seems to fall to the last else no matter how many times I input the function into the dev console.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVCgi.png

Comment: Can you try logging your `cookies` and check if you're comparing the right values?

Comment: `typeof document.cookie` always returns `"string"`. When there is no cookies, `document.cookie === ""` So your first `if` will never match.

Comment: I used console.log(cookies); cookies is actually ```const cookies = document.cookie``` and it turned up with d=0

Comment: Do the `console.log(cookies)` outside of any conditions, and see what you get. Then think a bit about whether that will ever match a format like `d = 0; path = /; expires: Tue, 16 Jun 2099 00:00:00 GMT;`

Comment: Yeah Doing it with each if helped more. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logged cookies I was able to determine that the system only read part of them. From this I am now able to edit it to work. Thanks Rinkesh Golwala! You just saved me from hours and hours of straight debugging to no avail.

You don't really need to comment anymore.